# How to implement CONNECT method in a proxy built with Apache HTTP components 4.x

Tags: ssl, proxy, apache-httpcomponents

I am developing a proxy using Apache HTTP Components 4.

When a browser wants to open an SSL connection through my proxy it sends a request with the HTTP CONNECT method.

How can I implement the CONNECT method using HTTP Components? How can I turn the HTTP connection (which is already handled by the HTTP components library) into a raw TCP connection that is proxied through my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a connection tunnel has been negotiated (CONNECT handshake has been successfully executed) and outgoing connection successfully established, your proxy should bypass the entire HTTP layer and start reading whatever stuff comes from the raw socket of the incoming connection and copying it to the raw socket of the outgoing connection, as well as reading whatever stuff comes form the socket of the outgoing connection and copying it to the socket of the incoming connection.

Comment: So how do I get the raw socket from HTTP Components? Without HTTP Components trying to close it or do anything more with it from that point onwards.

Comment: @Dr.Haribo: are you using blocking or non-blocking (NIO) transport? In any case both models are described in detail here http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/tutorial/html/index.html

Comment: I'm using the NIO transport. Perhaps I can use a ConnectingIOReactor to initiate the new raw TCP connection to the external site? It's not clear to me how to turn the existing proxy client connection into a raw TCP socket though, or how to access it in such a manner.

Comment: @Dr.Haribo: What you need is to get hold of IOSession. It is not exposed by default connection implementations but you can subclass them and provide a getter for IOSession. Here's a sample of reverse proxy http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore-nio/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/NHttpReverseProxy.java. You might want to subscribe to the HC dev list in case you have further questions.